# ImportError: No module named nibabel in python 2.7

Tags: pytorch

I am using python 2.7 and I used

```
pip install nibabel
```

but I constantly get the error

```
ImportError: No module named nibabel.
```

when I type

```
pip show nibabel
```

I get this result so it seems that it is installed but still get the aforementioned error when using import nibabel as nib

```
    Name: nibabel
Version: 2.5.0
Summary: Access a multitude of neuroimaging data formats
Home-page: https://nipy.org/nibabel
Author: nibabel developers
Author-email: neuroimaging@python.org
License: MIT License
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
Requires: six, numpy
Required-by:
```

Here the address shows it is installed in python3 path! How can I address this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install it using pip2:

`pip2 install nibabel`

Or explicitly call the pip module for Python 2.7:

`python2.7 -m pip install nibabel`

for example.